# Como alterar os media-query usando JS?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Estou usando CSS com os media queries, como por exemplo:

```
html {
  --color: #OOOOOO;
}


@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
 html {
   --color: #FFFFFF;
 }
}
```

---

Considerando o código acima, quem tem o `prefers-color-scheme` de `dark` terá `#FFFFFF` e quem não tem verá `#000000`. Nenhum problema até aí.

Porém, alguém pode preferir visualizar o conteúdo diferente do atual. Por exemplo, considerando que seu `prefers-color-scheme` é de `light`. Se você quiser visualizar o conteúdo como se fosse `dark` terá que ir até as configurações do navegador e alterar.

Existe alguma maneira, no JS, de sobrescrever a definição do navegador? **Forçar que você se torne um `prefers-color-scheme: dark`?!**

---

Existe alguma forma de sobrescrever estes parâmetros usando Javascript? Alguma coisa como:

```
window.document .MediaQueries .Set("prefers-color-scheme", "dark");
```

Dessa forma, independente do "prefers-color-scheme" atual do navegador, ele se tornaria "dark" e nada no CSS teria que ser alterado.

---

**Isso é possível de alguma forma?**

---

[*Utilizei o `prefers-color-scheme` para melhor exemplificar o problema, mas considere ver a publicação anterior.*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/444422/1)

Comment: Teria como fazer usando [`@custom-media`](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-5/#custom-mq)(Capitulo 4 e 4.1) mas a recomendação até o momento não foi implementada em nenhum browser.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma *solução*, que seria usando `cssRules`, que o [@Augusto Vasques mencionou num comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/444422/como-alterar-os-media-query-usando-js?noredirect=1#comment854653_444448).

---

Isso não é exatamente como queria, isso não vai funcionar com media-queries mais complexas (exemplo: min-width). Para que funcionasse iria exigir que criasse algum dicionário para depois recuperar os valores antigos.

Considerando, exatamente:

```
html {
  --color: #OOOOOO;
}


@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
 html {
   --color: #FFFFFF;
 }
}
```

Se estivéssemos executando o navegador com `light`, a cor será `#OOOOOO`. A minha pergunta seria como mudar o navegador para `dark`, **infelizmente isso não tem como e irei marcar qualquer outra resposta como válida que faça exatamente isso.**

O que temos como fazer é trocar o `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` para `@media (prefers-color-scheme: light)`, dessa forma a segunda variável substiuirá a anterior. Então como você está como `light` irá passar a usar `#FFFFFF`, porque o `dark` do CSS virou `light`.

---

Para fazer essa magia existe o `cssRules`, como mencionei antes. No total, meu código ficou algo como:

> **JS**:

```js
// Quando tiver mais tempo dou uma organizada no código, porque nem eu estou entendendo, simplesmente copiei o que fiz em Golang. Deve ter como fazer melhor em JS.


window.document.querySelector("fullscreen").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (!(e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement)) {
    return;
  }

  if (IsBrowser(e.target.dataset.mode)) {
    SetTheme("light", "dark"); // Mudamos para o padrão, já que quer usar aquilo que o seu navegador já é.
  } else {
    SetTheme("dark", "light"); // Mudamos para o oposto ao seu navegador (porque se estiver como "dark" o CSS virá "light"; se estiver usando como "light" passará a ser "light" e então o modo noturno será ativado).
  }
});

window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)").addEventListener("change", function (_) {
  SetTheme("light", "dark"); // Se você mudar no browser voltamos ao modo normal do CSS.
})


function IsBrowser(t) {
  return window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: " + t + ")").matches;
}

function SetTheme(o, n) {
  let rules = window.document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
  for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    media = rules[i].media
    if (media == undefined) {
      continue
    }

    current = media.mediaText
    current = current.replace("(prefers-color-scheme: " + o + ")", "(prefers-color-scheme: " + n + ")");

    rules[i].media.mediaText = current
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  --background: aqua;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html {
    --background: brown;
  }
}

fullscreen {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: var(--background);
}
```

```html
<fullscreen>
  <button data-mode=dark>Escuro</button>
  <button data-mode=light>Claro</button>
</fullscreen>
```

> **Golang:**

```
func SetTheme(old, new string) {
    rules := js.Global.Get("document").Get("styleSheets").Index(0).Get("cssRules")
    for i := 0; i < rules.Length(); i++ {
        media := rules.Index(i).Get("media")
        if media == js.Undefined {
            continue
        }

        current := media.Get("mediaText").String()
        current = strings.Replace(current, `(prefers-color-scheme: `+old+`)`, `(prefers-color-scheme: `+new+`)`, -1)
        media.Set("mediaText", current)
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que a resposta foi negativada? Poderia explicar a falha no raciocínio do AR ou qual parte da resposta que não funciona?